# WebApi Route is getting moved to base URL after publish

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api-routing, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I have a very simple route in an application that works fine from Visual Studio, but when I run through the publish process and deploy it to an IIS 8.5 server it changes the route and resolves from the base URL. I believe it has something to do with the route mappings, but I'm not sure why it's being interpreted differently.

When I launch in Visual Studio and visit http://localhost/test - it works great. If I visit http://localhost - I receive a 403 like I'd expect.

After I publish to IIS, the inverse happens. http://servername/test resolves to a 404, and http://servername now resolves my test page.

Any help would be appreciated in understanding this behavior. Visual Studio version is 2015, and IIS is version 8.5. WebAPI version is 5.2.3.

Controller:

```
[Route("test")]
public class WebApiController : ApiController
{
    private static readonly ILogger Logger = Log.Logger.ForContext<WebApiController>();
    [Route("")]
    public string Get()
    {
        return "Services started. Current response time is: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss tt");
    }
}
```

Route registration:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "Default",
            routeTemplate: "",
            defaults: new { }
        );
    }
```

Comment: just spit balling , try [RoutePrefix("test")] instead on [Route("test")] at top of the controller.

Comment: Looks like your default route is setup as your home page, but I am not sure what will happen if you don't setup any defaults. That probably explains why the `http://localhost` URL is working when it shouldn't - you should nuke that route and get routing working only on your attribute routes (or alternatively reset it back to the original API route).